# Mixing Kalman filter and least-squares

Tags: linear-systems, estimation, kalman-filters

I'm not sure it is the right department. I try my chance

I am wondering if there is a way to make a hybrid formulation of a least-square problem and a Kalman filter. Let me explain what I mean:

The (linear) least-square formulation reads for a set of observation $y \in \mathbb{R}^{q}$

$$\hat x = \min_x {\epsilon^\top \epsilon}\quad \text{subject to} \quad y = C x + L \epsilon$$

with $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^q$ , $C \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times n}$, $L \in \mathbb R^{q\times q}$ (weighting matrix) and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the state to be estimated.

Kalman filter makes use of a dynamical model for the state and a linear mapping from the observation to the state

\begin{align}
 x_k & = A_k x_{k-1} + B_k u_{k} + w_k \\
 y_k & = C_k x_k + v_k
\end{align}

Where $w_k$ and $v_k$ (plant and measurement noise) account for uncertainty in the model. $u_k \in \mathbb{R}^p$ some known imput.

Although I understand good both least-squares and Kalman filters I was wondering how to build a hybrid formulation of the both. I've been asked to create a model for **a part only** of the state (call it $\tilde x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $m < n$). I now managed to find a linear model that I'm happy with.

To include my model I perform a Kalman filter on $\tilde x$ and then on the rest of the state $x \backslash \tilde x \in \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ (not the best notation sorry) I perform the least-square problem (already developed by someone else). It doesn't seem to give me good results though... I also tried to use the estimate of the filter as an observation entering the least-squares (the result is better, still less good than simple least-square without KF).

Is there a way to formulate the whole thing only as a least-square problem? I'm imagining something like using the prediction part of the Kalman filter algorithm

$$\tilde x_{k/ k-1} = A_k \tilde x_{k-1/ k-1} + B_k u_k$$

and then include the update step somehow directly in the least-squares.

$$\tilde x_{k/ k} = \tilde x_{k/ k-1} + K_k (\tilde y_k - C_k \tilde x_{k/ k-1})$$

I think it should be possible because it also uses the information of the observations $y$. Otherwise any other ideas would be most welcome!

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

I saw in "*Filtering and system identification a least squares approach* Michel Verhaegen, Vincent Verdult" something called the stochastic least squares. I think it is the idea I'm looking for. Basically instead of simply solving $y = Cx$, if the mean of $x$ (call it $\overline x$) and its covariance $P$ are known the least-square problem can be augmented and one can find two matrices $M$, $N$ such that $$\hat x = \begin{bmatrix}M & N \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y \\ \overline x \end{bmatrix}$$

minimizes the covariance (i.e. $\mathbb E \left((x - \hat x)(x - \hat x)^\top\right)$ is minimum) and unbiased ($\mathbb E (\hat x) =  \overline x$). I would use the prediction step to compute $\overline x$

$$ \overline x := \tilde x_{k/k-1}.$$
$$ P := P_{k/k-1}$$

However, in order to use the recursive least-squares (already implemented in a fancy and computationally optimized way in the code), I need more of an identity like

$$ \begin{bmatrix} y \\ \overline x \end{bmatrix} = \widetilde C \tilde x$$

This is basically adding the prediction part of the filter as an observer in the least-squares.

I have a strong feeling that there is a nice way of doing that but couldn't figure it out. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Hi:  Can you not just formulate the whole problem as a KF and then put zeros in for the variances of the states that don't evolve. ( i.e: the ones that you want to do a regression on ). I may not be understanding your question exactly but I think it's possible to do what you want.  This might be somewhat helpful also. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1972.10481299

Comment: Hi: Thanks for the prompt answer. 
I think you mean more infinity (or rather a large variance) in the state that don't evolve and give them a trivial evolution like $x_k = x_{k-1}$ but in the lab they don't want that. The whole problem is now solved in a static way for each time step combining recursive least-squares with PDE solving until convergence. Basically the PDE gives me the magnetic flux and the RLS uses measurement and this flux to obtain the current in some coils which is feeded in the PDE solver etc. They built fancy C function so it can work in real time that I'm asked to keep.

Comment: Thanks for the article I'm reading it. Hopefully, I find inspiration. I also edit my question for clarity

Comment: okay. I'm sorry my idea about zero variance didn't help. I'll print out your edited question and read it again but  now it sounds well beyond my pay grade :).

Comment: Thank you vers much :)

Comment: Does $\tilde x$ depend on $\tilde x \setminus x$?  If not, then you can just do the math separately.  If the dynamics of $\tilde x$ does depend on $\tilde x \setminus x$ then you have to take that into account in your Kalman filter.  Can you give a more complete model of the system in your question?